# Undefined method `courses' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I visit the courses/new page on my heroku app, it raises an error saying that the method courses is not defined. Also, when I create a course on the console, it has no id or created_at.

Courses Controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @course = current_user.courses.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @course = current_user.courses.build
  end

  def create
    @course = current_user.courses.build(course_params)
    if @course.save
      flash[:success] = "Course Created"
      redirect_to coursehome_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def course_params
     params.require(:course).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

College Model:

```
class College < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
  has_secure_password
  def College.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? 
    BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

Course model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :college
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :college, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :courses, [:college_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Edit:

Actually, I created a controller called collegesessions and added the current_user method in its helper:

```
module CollegesessionsHelper
  def log_in(college)
    session[:user_id] = college.id
  end

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= College.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

 def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: post your user model.

Comment: You have `courses` being accessed via `current_user`. The only references you've created come from `college`.

Comment: When you create `Course` object it must have at least `id`. Did you mean `college_id` ?

Comment: @zeitnot No, it had a college_id but not an id

Comment: Ok. It seems that `current_user` is `nil`. So use `College.find(id: session[:user_id])` to ensure that if there is a user id.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to access
`current_user.courses`, it looks for courses association in `user`model.

Your course model has no `user` association.

**Course Model**

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :college
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    //fields

    has_many: courses

end
```

Comment: `current_user` is actually `College` class.